# SSIS import using foreign key data?

Tags: ssis, foreign-key-relationship

I have an old database (`OldDB`) with a table (let's call it `Call`) that I'm using SSIS (2008) and a new database (`NewDB`) with the following setup:

- `OldDB.Call` has a column called `Status`which currently is varchar(1) and holds values such as "C", "D", etc.
- `NewDB` now maps all the possible statuses in its own table with a foreign key constraint so that `OldDB.Call.Status` is now `NewDB.CallStatus.id` An example of the data in the `NewDB.Call.StatusID` would be `1`,`2`, `3` and so forth.
- `NewDB.CallStatus` now has a column called `Status` which holds the actual nvarchar(1) value of `A`,`B`, `C`, etc.

I'm using SSIS to migrate the data. So far, I know I need to use a Sort transformation for each source and then a Merge Join transformation to map the new `NewDB.Call.StatusID` to the `OldDB.Call.Status` value. For whatever reason, it seems to start just fine but ends up grabbing other columns (like a description column, for example) and shoves the wrong kind of data in there. In short, it's not mapping the foreign key like it should.

I've found numerous examples on the web on how to do this ([like this](http://www.ssistutorial.com/create_join_between_datasets_in_ssis.php)) but it seems like I'm missing some key, critical piece of information in order to understand what I'm doing because I keep borking it.

In a perfect world, a step-by-step would be great but a good and concise tutorial or explanation would be useful as well. **In short, I need to know how to hook those two tables up and map the value in `OldDB` to the foreign key in the the `NewDB` and store that value in `NewDB.CallStatus`.**

Comment: Two things. First: can you post some screen shots of your package so we can get a better idea of what you're missing.  Without that we are just kind of guessing. Second: it's not generally considered good to have a column that's varchar(1) since it's not variable length. It's always 1.

Comment: The varchar(1) is legacy that we're doing away with, thankfully. Aaand I can't do a screenshot anymore because it was far faster to just do it as a join in sql script - we wanted to automate in SSIS but... it's already done so... Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Lookup Transformation for this requirement.

Within the Lookup definition, the Connection would point to your NewDB.CallStatus (writing a SELECT is best practice, rather than just choosing the table - it caches the metadata). On the Columns pane, map Status to Status, and choose StatusID as a Lookup column.

Now your data flow will carry that added column downstream, and you can deliver it (typically using an OLE DB Destination).

Lookup's default mode is Full Cache which will be much faster and use much less Memory compared to a Sort & Merge solution.